# Easily splitting out multiple saved mean values into separate macro variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set with a ton of variables. For example:

```
ID  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8
1   4   1   2   2   2   2   1   2
2   2   3   1   4   3   4   4   2
3   3   5   1   3   4   3   4   3
4   3   1   2   3   2   2   4   2
5   5   1   5   5   3   5   1   5
...
```

I want to take the average of each variable, store it, and then be able to use it for other data sets.

What I have tried so far is for each variable, over and over:

```
proc means data=data;
var v1; 
output out=v1out mean=meanv1;
run;
proc means data=data;
var v2; 
output out=v2out mean=meanv2;
run;
...
```

then, for each (again):

```
data v1temp;
  set v1;
  call symput("meanv1",meanv1);
run;
data v2temp;
  set v2;
  call symput("meanv2",meanv2);
run;
...
```

But this is very tedious with a lot of variables. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Try aggregate the whole data set by means, or use macro to fold the long codes into one small chunk.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, can you explain how to aggregate by means?

Comment: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/261-30.pdf, see pages 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to take the average of each variable, store it, and then be
>   able to use it for other data sets.

There doesn't seem to be an advantage to using global macro variables for this. Another option is to calculate the means as @user102890 suggests above:

```
proc means data = myData noprint;
var v1-v8;
output out = myDataMeans(drop = _type_ _freq_ 
                                     where = (_stat_='MEAN')
                                      rename = (v1-v8 = meanV1-meanV8));
run;
```

And then just set that one observation into your data set:

```
DATA myData;
    set myData;
    if _N_ = 1 then set myDataMeans;

    ...;
RUN;
```

Then you have variables `meanV1-meanV8` available as actual data set values on every observation of data set `data`. You could do the same thing for any other data set for which you want to use the means of those variables.

Comment: Ah, ok. So if I, for example, wanted to replace all missing values in a variable with the mean of that variable, would I just write `if v1=. then v1=meanv1; if v2=. then v2=meanv2;...` after that "set" statement? Or do I have to do `&meanv1` (or some sort of leader)?

Comment: Exactly, you can just refer to `meanv1`, `meanv2` as normal variables. If there are lot of variables, you could also put the `v1-v8` and `meanv1-meanv8` variables into separate arrays and replace the missing values in a loop across the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Behold the power of PROC SQL;)

```
data myData;
input id v1-v8;
datalines;
1   4   1   2   2   2   2   1   2
2   2   3   1   4   3   4   4   2
3   3   5   1   3   4   3   4   3
4   3   1   2   3   2   2   4   2
5   5   1   5   5   3   5   1   5
;
run;

proc transpose  data= myData out= myXData;
    by id;
    var v1-v8;
run;

proc sql noprint;   
    select mean( col1 )
    into :mean1 - :mean8
    from myXData
    group by _name_
    ;
quit;

%put &mean1 &mean2 &mean3 &mean4 &mean5 &mean6 &mean7 &mean8;
```

Log output:

```
171
172  %put &mean1 &mean2 &mean3 &mean4 &mean5 &mean6 &mean7 &mean8;
3.4 2.2 2.2 3.4 2.8 3.2 2.8 2.8
```

I still concur the macro variables are not the best way storing sequential data.

Answer (score 0):

```
data myData;
input id v1-v8;
datalines;
1   4   1   2   2   2   2   1   2
2   2   3   1   4   3   4   4   2
3   3   5   1   3   4   3   4   3
4   3   1   2   3   2   2   4   2
5   5   1   5   5   3   5   1   5
;
run;

proc means data = myData noprint;
var v1-v8;
output out = myDataMeans(drop = _type_ _freq_ 
                                     where = (_stat_='MEAN')
                                      rename = (v1-v8 = meanV1-meanV8));
run;
```

The output datset, `myDataMeans` looks like the following:

```
_STAT_ meanV1 meanV2 meanV3 meanV4 meanV5 meanV6 meanV7 meanV8
MEAN     3.4    2.2    2.2    3.4    2.8    3.2    2.8   2.8
```

The following will read the `myDataMeans` dataset and put each column in it into its own macro variable.

```
%let dsid=%sysfunc(open(myDataMeans,i));/*open the dataset which has macro vars to read in cols*/
%syscall set(dsid); /*no leading ampersand with %SYSCALL */
%let rc=%sysfunc(fetchobs(&dsid,1));/*just reading 1 obs*/
%let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));/*close dataset after reading*/
%put _user_;
```

The following global macro variables are created as shown in the log:

```
GLOBAL _STAT_ MEAN    
GLOBAL MEANV1 3.4
GLOBAL MEANV2 2.2
GLOBAL MEANV3 2.2
GLOBAL MEANV4 3.4
GLOBAL MEANV5 2.8
GLOBAL MEANV6 3.2
GLOBAL MEANV7 2.8
GLOBAL MEANV8 2.8
```

Comment: Cool. This definitely does what I asked, but I guess what I asked was not the best way to accomplish the task I wanted.